# Blu-ray through VGA connector problems

Tags: hdmi, dvi, vga, blu-ray

I recently purchased a Blu-ray drive to go in my PC. Both hardware and software was installed successfully.

I have a dual-monitor setup, one of which is a TV. Currently a DVI connector on my graphics card goes through a [DVI to VGA adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004G3WCLM/ref=asc_df_B004G3WCLM6159386?smid=A2C4VTXYA0IDAF&tag=hydra0b-21&linkCode=asn&creative=22218&creativeASIN=B004G3WCLM) which plugs into a VGA on the TV. This works and my computer detects a 1080p TV correctly.

My main monitor is plugged in using the only HDMI connector on my graphics card.

When I play a blu-ray it will appear on my main monitor correctly. If I drag the window to my TV, a message pops up stating that the video can not be played and that I need a DVI or HDMI connection.

Already I'm a bit lost on the technicalities, in my mind if the TV can receive a 1080p picture through VGA I see no reason why kicking the signal out from a blu-ray should make any difference. Regardless, I am now after a solution.

I can't use the DVI to my monitor as it's a 3D monitor and must use the HDMI connection. So, I found this [DVI to HDMI adapter](http://www.dabs.com/products/startech-com-hdmidvifm---video-adapter---dual-lnk---19-pin-hdmi--f----dvi-d--m----black-4LQQ.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=product%20search&utm_content=Q200). Would something as simple as this work? As I don't really understand why VGA doesn't work I can't see how this would make any difference, to me they are all digital signals it's just the shape of the connector, or is that not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching Blu-ray content is copy protected and requires an interface which supports [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) (a similar principle to Macrovision on analogue video) to enable viewing.

HDCP is only available over Display Port, HDMI or DVI connections so your DVI-VGA adapter is removing the HDCP data. Your monitor will also need to be HDCP compliant.

***If*** both the DVI-HDMI adapter and the monitor are HDCP compliant then it should work.

This article has some useful info:

http://www.hometheaterhifi.com/volume_11_4/feature-dvi-hdmi-hdcp-connections-11-2004.html

Comment: Seems to make sense, in which case - to follow up - will purchasing the DVI to HDMI adapter work correctly? If they are both using this HDCP technology one would assume it works across the adapter.

Comment: I think it must specifically be a DVI-D to HDMI adapter but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: http://intrl.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/HDMI/HDMI-Female-to-DVI-Male-Adapter~HDMIDVIFM

Comment: That seems perfect, by the sounds of it I may need to check my TV as well to ensure that's using this HDCP technology. To try and sound clever, it presumably is? If I had bought a standalone Blu-ray player, this presumably would connect without any problems so the TVs HDMI port is likely to be compliant?

Comment: The TV should be compliant, you can test it by temporarily connecting the HDMI from computer to TV instead of monitor and see if a Blu-ray plays on it.

Comment: Ah good plan! That's brilliant thank you for your help. If I remember I will come back if/when I have the adapter to let people know if it works.

Comment: As an update for anyone with a similar problem, the plan suggested by Shevek worked perfectly, although I didn't specifically buy a DVI-D adapter it was just a very cheap £1.50 purchase off ebay (http://gard.me/VEhA1).